# Python - download excel file from email attachment then parse it

Tags: python, excel, file, outlook

**EDIT - UPDATE**
I have created a horrible hack that opens the excel file then saves it down with the same filename before then opening the excel file into pandas. This is really horrible but I can't see any other way to solve the problem as attachment.SaveFileAs creates and endian problem.

I have the following code that finds an email in my outlook then downloads the excel file to a directory. There is a problem when I try and open the file to parse it and use it for another part in my script it comes up with a formatting error.

I know this is caused from the way Python saves it down as when I do it manually it works fine.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import email
import datetime as date
import pandas as pd
import os

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = date.date.today()

sub_today = 'Hi'
att_today = 'Net - Regional.xls'

## loop through inbox attachments
for msg in all_inbox:
    yourstring = msg.Subject.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    if(yourstring.find('Regional Reporting Week') != -1):
        break

## get attachments
for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        attachments = msg.Attachments
        break

attachment = attachments.Item(1)
fn = os.getcwd() + '\\' + att_today
attachment.SaveASFile(fn)

# terrible hack but workable in the short term
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fn)
wb.SaveAs(fn)
wb.Close(True)

xl = pd.ExcelFile(fn)
data_df = xl.parse("RawData - Global")
print(data_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the file name string of att_today? Is it using the appropriate extension?

You're saving it as a ".xls" file. Could it possibly be a ".xlsx" extension?

Asides from the ".SaveAsFile()" method, you may want to look into ".ExtractFile" or "WriteToFile".

Lastly, even if Python may be saving it differently from how you manually saved it, you could still possibly use some 3rd-Party Excel packages to read the file properly before re-writing it for manual opening / viewing.

For ".xls" extensions, I would recommend XLRD.
For ".xlsx" extensions, I would recommend OpenPyxl.